# Cross platform C++ in C# .net Core/5 application

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, swig

With the introduction of .net Core, and more recently, .net 5, cross-platform .net/C# is relatively easy.
With this in mind, I'm working towards an application that would use .net 5/C#, but there is some code that I want to keep in the C++/native domain. With C# only, one can even publish to other platforms from the development one. I'm willing to give up on that.

Now, how can one keep the project cross-platform?

I've been looking everywhere an there doesn't seem to be a great option anywhere...

Maybe [this solution from Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/cpp/)?  I'm not sure it'll translate to Desktop, or that it can be automatized on a CI/CD...

But other than that, everybody seems to get away with their own janky way.

Does anybody have pointers about C(++)/C# integration that's cross platform?

**Edit 1:**

My problem is not to make the interop per se. I have successfully used SWIG and I know about P/Invoke, C-compatible ABIs and etc.

My problem is build system/deployment. So far I have to copy files around. But how can one have an integrated build system? I want that when building my dotnet app for the C++ libraries to compile, for example.

Answer (score 5):

You can have C++/C# without any problems. But the "bridge" methods between the C++ side and the C# side **must** accept/return plain C types/structs. **You can't pass around `std::xxxx` full stop**. You can pass around `char *str`, `struct { int Foo, int Bar }`, `int[]` and so on (but still there is a little complexity, depending on how it is done).

I maintain a [github](https://github.com/xanatos/CSharpCPlusPlusInteropSamples/tree/main/) of examples about marshaling strings and structs from/to C/C++ to C# on .NET Framework/.NET Core. The project is built for Visual Studio, so there are some "microsoftnesses" inside, but the basic ideas can be copied-pasted onto other C platforms easily.

There are some additional complexities when you want to do a fully multiplaform project (I didn't think about crossplatforming when I wrote those examples):

1. The encoding of strings: in the examples I show that you can use utf-8 strings easily, but it is still a pain, because on Windows the Windows API don't support utf-8 and are tailored for `wchar_t` (you can't `CreateFile` with an utf-8 filename). On the opposite side on Linux everyone uses `char*` and nearly no one uses `wchar_t*` (to give the same example, [filesystems on Linux are agnostic about character sets](https://superuser.com/a/358861/99869), so the `open` primitive and the `fopen` method can accept `char*` that can be utf-8 encoded), so deciding how to handle `char`/`wchar_t` in a crossplatform way is a pain. If I had to do it, I would probably define the `TCHAR` macro to be `char` on Linux, `wchar_t` on Windows, use it everywhere, and use the `LPTStr` marshalling option for strings, and the `Auto` methods for the `Marshal` class (`Marshal.PtrToStringAuto` for example). The .NET Core considers `LPTStr`/`xxxAuto` to be `char*` on Linux and `wchar_t*` on Windows.
2. While on Windows there is a great deluge of memory allocators (the main ones used by .NET Core in interop are the `CoTaskMemAlloc` for memory and the `SysAllocString` for strings, but there are niche (useles) things like `GlobalHAlloc`), on Linux .NET Core uses directly `malloc`. This is important for freeing memory allocated "from the other side", and it increases the complexity if you want to be able to let the marshaller free automatically the memory. But in the end it is always a good idea to expose a memory deallocator from the C/C++ side, because before or later you'll have to free memory allocated in the C/C++ side. And while possible I think it is a bad idea to let the marshaller free automagically the memory allocated C/C++ side (because you don't have control on the operation, and you can't easily debug it). So no `char* Foo()` translated in C# with `string Foo()`: it is possible to do it, but the .NET marshaller will use `CoTaskMemFree` to free it. There are other ways to do it, or you can do it manually (`IntPtr Foo()` and then you convert and free the `IntPtr` explicitly).
3. There are some limitations about using `BSTR` and `SAFEARRAY` under Linux (the main problem is that there are no reciprocal methods C side), so if you want to program crossplatform it is a bad idea using them (but no one uses them)

Comment: I know well about ABIs,`extern "C"` and to make things be functions instead of classed for easy FFIs. There are also things like SWIG and CppSharp. What you present is still a vcxproj, so it can't be build for Linux or MacOS. I'm interested in cross-platform, that's the whole point of the question.

Comment: @RuiOliveira Expanded the response. I haven't ever used both of the libraries, but every time I've seen something done with SWIG it was a pain to fix any problem that was present. Using libraries like that could be a good idea if the "surface" that must be exported is very big (tens and tens of methods). If you only have to export a handful of methods (a more common scenario) then they are probably overblown and introduce complexities and hide things that should be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, but my problem really isn't how to interface C#/C++. It's really about how to build such a project in a cross platform and automatic way.

Comment: @RuiOliveira It is your project in the end. What I can say to you is this: there are 170 questions about [Swig] + [C#] (plus this one) on SO at this time. If you have problems with Swig you are on your own. For [CppSharp] it is even worse. I think 6 questions. Good luck! 

Answer (score 1):

There are three aspects:

1. The .NET/native interop
2. The deployment and packaging of the native component library
3. Deployment of the entire application bundle, i.e. the managed and native parts

Obviously you need to maintain versions and builds of your native component for all supported platforms. That is a challenge on its own but not related to using it from .NET. With regard to 1) you will need to provide an API for your native library which is compatible with the standardized PInvoke specification. This might be challenging depending on what your component does and might cause trouble if not done right. If you can, prefer pure managed code only, if you are ready for the challenge, proceed!

Comment: Building and deploying is for sure my problem for out. Do you have insights on that?

Comment: Yes, sure, but it is difficult to give recommendations without further information about your project. In general, you will need some sort of setup for cross platform builds with unified conventions for naming, bitness, managing of dependencies etc. CMake and VcPkg are your friends.